# Working with Maple toolbox for Matlab

Tags: matlab, maple

I have a big project in matlab that I've been writing for months. It includes a lot of code related to equations. The code worked with Matlab symbolic engine (or maybe it was Mupad I'm not sure). I wanted to switch to Maple symbolic engine so I downloaded Maple toolbox for Matlab. Now I can't run my code anymore since matlab doesn't recognize commands like 'vpasolve' (solve numeric equations), 'children' (finds subexpressions of a given expression), etc..

I'm looking for a long time for a tutorial that explains how to work with Maple toolbox for matlab that can expain in details what changes I need to make in my code to make it work. For example, I have no idea what to write instead of the 'children' command.
I didn't find any tutorial.
The best I've found so far is this link:

http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/programs/Matlab/maplesymbolic.html

but It explains only a little and I still don't know what to do with many of the commands that I need to change (like 'children').

Can anyone suggest how I can change my code to make it work? or send me a link that explains that (if exists). I know a little Maple (mostly works with Matlab).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest Maple analog to Mupad's [vpasolve](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpasolve.html) seems to be [fsolve](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=fsolve).

The closest Maple analog to Mupad's [children](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/children.html) seems to be [op](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=op) . Note that it returns a sequence, but of course you can wrap the result in a list (square brackets) or a Vector or Matrix. It does not automatically map across Matrices and Vectors and lists.

Eg,

```
restart;

op( x^2 + x*y = y^2 + 1 );

                     2         2
                    x  + x y, y  + 1

M := Matrix( [ [ x + y, sin(x)*cos(y) ],
               [ x^3 - y^3, exp(x*y^2) ] ] );

                 [ x + y     sin(x) cos(y)]
            M := [                        ]
                 [ 3    3             2   ]
                 [x  - y       exp(x y )  ]

s := map(op, M);

               [  (x, y)       (sin(x), cos(y))]
          s := [                               ]
               [   3    3              2       ]
               [ (x , -y )          x y        ]
```

I got an overview of commands in the Mupad based symbolic toolbox for Matlab [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/functionlist.html).

Your question is more about programming than mathematics, and as such would be better suited to [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) or [Mapleprimes](http://www.mapleprimes.com). The latter is a Maple user community and its members might be able to help with more complicated examples.

[edited followup to comment]

I am not aware of a URL that shows side-by-side comparison of commands in the Mupad versus Maple.

```
restart;

exp1:=Matrix([[a,b],[c,d]]):

exp2:=Matrix([[y,7],[-4,p]]):

zip( `=`, exp1, exp2 ); # returns a Matrix

                   [a = y     b = 7]
                   [               ]
                   [c = -4    d = p]

Equate( exp1, exp2 ); # returns a list

              [a = y, b = 7, c = -4, d = p]
```

Some commands and operators will not automatically map over Vector/Matrix/Array/list in Maple, but the commands [map](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=map) and [zip](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=zip) can be used to get similar effects.

Comment: Thank you! I will ask next time in stackoverflow/Mapleprimes. I will check the 'op' command. didn't know about this command before. but still, the two commands that I mentioned were only examples. Is there a link that explains about it in details so I won't need to ask about each command in stackoverflow?
One more command that I'm still stuck in converting. 'eq=exp1==exp2' (where exp1 and exp2 are 3x3 matrices of symbolic expressions). In Mupad engine it defined eq as a matrix of equations but in maple engine eq is a logical matrix (all zeros). How can I write the equivalent?

Comment: I've added some followup.

Comment: Thank you again. but the code you wrote is pure Maple code right? the code that I need to write is in matlab (with maple engine). Can I write the code that you wrote above in matlab?

Comment: I don't know how Matlab works to allow commands to be passed through to the underlying symbolic engine. It *might* be the case that the commands it can pass through to Maple (as symbolic engine) are the exports of the Maple package `MTM`. That is just a guess. If correct then see https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=MTM

Comment: ok I will look it up. Thanks for all your help!